# Problem with audio while recording video

Tags: android, video, android-video-player

I am able to record video but I am not getting audio for that video.
Can any one help me to record video&audio at same time.
my code is as follows:

```
mr = new MediaRecorder();
mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);       
mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mr.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
mPreview = new Preview(RecordVideo.this,mr);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

when I put audioSource and audioEncoder its getting runtime error:
log cat details are:

```
05-07 10:17:01.175: ERROR/MediaRecorder(22990): setAudioEncoder called in an invalid state(2)
05-07 10:17:01.175: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22990):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)
```

when I remove those audioSource and audioEncoder from code its working fine for video without audio.
I need to have audio also with video
thanks in advance:

Comment: thanks for your reply...Ya I have added log cat...

Comment: Shekher, class android.media.MediaPlayer don't contains method setVideoSource. What MediaPlayer you use?

Comment: Maybe, you forgot for some permissions for microphone?

Comment: I have two buttons audio and video....Its recording audio fine when its comes to video its not getting video

Comment: Do you try other audio encoders?

Comment: yes I have tried audio encoders...

Comment: Should I need to give audio separately while recording video???

Answer (score 19):

You should call `setAudioEncoder()` after `setOutputFormat()`.