# MediaRecorder: audio source is set, but audio encoder is not set

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

I use `Camera`, `Mediarecorder`,`mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(0.1)`, and `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW`. I do not know what the problem is.

Code:

private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

```
    if(mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    }
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 5.5: Set the video capture rate to a low number
    mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(0.1); // capture a frame every 10 seconds

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d("ADS", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ADS", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Error:

```
11-12 17:07:52.942 18218-18218/ivanzar.ads E/MediaRecorder: audio source is set, but audio encoder is not set
11-12 17:07:52.942 18218-18218/ivanzar.ads D/ADS: IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code to record videos:

```
@Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
                    mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
                    Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

                    List<Camera.Size> listSize;

                    listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                    Camera.Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(0);
                    p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
                    mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

                    try {
                        mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mServiceCamera.startPreview();

                    mServiceCamera.unlock();

                    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
                    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
                    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
                    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + STrVideoname);
                    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
                    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
                    try {
                        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mMediaRecorder.start();

                    mRecordingStatus = true;


                }
```

Comment: Not work MediaRecorder: setAudioEncoder called in an invalid state(2), java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                 at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)

Comment: Put above code after mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER); and check if it working or not

Comment: I decided not to use capture rate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909382/problem-with-audio-while-recording-video

Comment: I saw the question

Comment: Do you know how to record some short videos that send them to server ?

Comment: you mean to recored like couple of  10s videos  continiously and send all them to server?

Comment: No, I do not correctly translated, oh my English, I wanted to write a some short vidio that faster send them to server. I can send video file to server, but can't recorder some short video.

Comment: I used this if(mVideoCaptureUtils.isRecording())
                {
                    if(mVideoCaptureUtils.getMediaRecorder() != null)
                    {
                        try {
                            mVideoCaptureUtils.stop(CameraUtils.getCamera());
                        }catch (RuntimeException ex){
                            //TODO: Edit it ignore someday
                        }

                    } , but i think it is bad.

Comment: No, i used handelr

Comment: check my answer

Comment: You forget set encoder mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);